# Outputting Bubble sorting

Tags: python, bubble-sort

I have this list called countries.txt that list all the countries by their name, area(in km2), population (eg. `["Afghanistan", 647500.0, 25500100]`).

```
def readCountries(filename):

    result=[]
    lines=open(filename)

    for line in lines:
        result.append(line.strip('\n').split(',\t'))
    for sublist in result:
        sublist[1]=float(sublist[1])
        sublist[2]=int(sublist[2])
```

I am trying to sort through the list using a bubble sort according to the are of each country:

```
>> c = countryByArea(7)
>>> c 

>>["India",3287590.0,1239240000]
```

When typing in the parameter is should return the nth largest area.

I have this but I'm not sure how to output the information

```
def countryByArea(area):
    myList=readCountries('countries.txt')

    for i in range(0,len(list)):
        for j in range(0,len(list)-1):
            if list[j]>list[j+1]:
                temp=list[j]
                list[j]=list[j+1]
                list[j+1]=temp
```

Comment: Any reason why bubble sort?

Comment: `print` will print stuff ... imagine that ... Im pretty sure bubble sort wants a flag to tell it if its sorted ... in fact im pretty sure this wont sort correctly

Comment: @cricket_007 clearly its an assignment of some sort ... probably to teach them basic sorting algorithms that they wont use beyond an interview ...

Comment: Yeah, the second code block doesn't work -  `list` is a function name in python, `range` is misspelled, and `myList` is never used or returned from 'readCountries`

Answer (score 0):

first of all, implement a generic bubble sort method.  this is a correct bubble sort algorithm implementation... Im sure you can find other implementations on http://rosettacode.org

```
def bubble_sort(a_list,a_key):
    changed=True
    while changed:
        changed = False
        for i in range(len(a_list)-1):
            if a_key(a_list[i]) > a_key(a_list[i+1]):
                a_list[i],a_list[i+1] = a_list[i+1],a_list[i]
                changed = True
```

then simply pass a key function that represents the data you want to sort by (in this case the middle value or index one of each row

```
import csv    
def sort_by_area(fname):
     with open(fname) as f:
        a = list(csv.reader(f))
     bubble_sort(a,lambda row:int(row[1]))
     return a

a = sort_by_area("a_file.txt")    
print a[-7] #the 7th largest by area
```

you can take this info and combine it to complete your assignment ... but really this is a question you should have asked a classmate or your teacher for help with ...